# Cocoa touch framework embed other libraries

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift2, cocoa-touch

They asked me to create a cocoatouch framework that bundles all off our 3th party frameworks. So that we can use that framework all over the company.

Now I think it's better when you make the application responsible for adding the dependencies that your framework need but this not possible here.

So I created a framework added some frameworks like PureLayout.framework, etc.. and added them to the linked frameworks and libraries.

It compiles and delivers a .framework but when I add that framework to the project and run it, then I get this error:

dyld: Library not loaded
Reason: image not found

So I think they are only linked against and not embedded in the framework.
How can I really embed them?